# Define preamble to a default

Tags: environments

I have

```
\begin{arab}[utf]
... some text
\end{arab}
```

throughout entire document.

Is there any way to get rid of this reoccurring `\begin` `\end` command so to have my document look like this:

```
\begin{document}

text1

\newpage

text 2

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Can you add a minimal preamble?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{\quote}
\AtEndDocument{\endquote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Just replace the `quote` with `arab`, wasn't sure from where you got that to test it.

You might also want to get rid of `...begin{document}`...`\end{document}` altogether as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{\quotation}
\AtEndDocument{\endquotation}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\arabic\document
\let\endarabic\enddocument
\begin{arabic}
\lipsum
\end{arabic}
```

Comment: Nice definitions using `\let`. Genius!